# Java Hashmap- displaying a message and adding a return?

Tags: java, hashmap, return, maps, return-value

I've created the below code using a hashmap to display players in a scoreboard. Now I've got one issue with it.

And last of all I've implemented the code to add a player that already exists but I'm having trouble displaying a message that says the player already exists.

Any help is appreciated and I mean any. Ask me questions and lets solve these small issues.

```
package javamaptest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class JavaMapTest
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Map mplayer = new HashMap();

            mplayer.put("Carlsen, Magnus", "Country:NOR,  Rating:(2876),  DOB:1990");
            mplayer.put("Anand, Viswanathan", "Country:IND,  Rating:(2804),  DOB:1969");
            mplayer.put("Caruana, Fabiano", "Country:ITA,  Rating:(2803),  DOB:1992");
            mplayer.put("Nakamura, Hikaru", "Country:USA,  Rating:(2799),  DOB:1987");
            mplayer.put("Topalov, Veselin", "Country:BUL,  Rating(2798), DOB:1975");
            mplayer.put("Grischuk, Alexander", "Country:RUS,  Rating:(2780), DOB:1983");
            mplayer.put("So, Wesley", "Country:USA,  Rating:(2778),  DOB:1993");
            mplayer.put("Kramnik, Vladimir", "Country:RUS,  Rating:(2777),  DOB:1975");
            mplayer.put("Giri, Anish", "Country:NED,  Rating:(2776),  DOB:1994");
            mplayer.put("Aronian, Levon", "Country:ARM,  Rating:(2776),  DOB:1982");
            mplayer.put("Ding, Liren", "Country:CHN,  Rating:(2757),  DOB:1992");
            mplayer.put("Vachier-Lagrave, Maxime", "Country:FRA,  Rating:(2754),  DOB:1990");
            mplayer.put("Karjakin, Sergey", "Country:RUS,  Rating:(2753), DOB:1990");
            mplayer.put("Navara, David", "Country:CZE,  Rating:(2751),  DOB:1985");
            mplayer.put("Tomashevsky, Evgeny", "Country:RUS,  Rating:(2749),  DOB:1987");
            mplayer.put("Li, Chao b", "Country:CHN,  Rating:(2748),  DOB:1989");
            mplayer.put("Woitaszek, Radoslaw", "Country:POL,  Rating:(2746),  DOB:1987");
            mplayer.put("Gelfand, Boris", "Country:ISR,  Rating:(2744),  DOB:1968");
            mplayer.put("Adam, Michael", "Country:ENG,  Rating:(2740),  DOB:1971");
            mplayer.put("Jakovenko, Dmitry", "Country:RUS,  Rating:(2738),  DOB:1983");
            // Below I added a pre existing player
            mplayer.put("Jakovenko, Dmitry", "Country:RUS,  Rating:(2738),  DOB:1983");

            Iterator iter = mplayer.entrySet().iterator();

            while (iter.hasNext())
            {
                Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
                System.out.println(mEntry.getKey() + " : " + mEntry.getValue());
            }
            // This I find a player with a given key
            mplayer.get("Carlsen, Magnus");
            mplayer.get("Anand, Viswanathan");

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Carlson, Magnus key information : " + mplayer.get("Carlsen, Magnus"));
            System.out.println("Anand, Viswanathan key information : " + mplayer.get("Anand, Viswanathan")); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return          
    }
}
```

Comment: `main` should be `void`, so no `return` necessary.

Comment: Well what do you *want* to return? And why have you made your main method return `boolean` anyway? Normally `main` is a `void` method. As for the remaining questions: you should ask *one* question per post, with a [mcve] where appropriate (this question contains more code than necessary), and without the appeals to not downvote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking three questions. It should be edited to ask a single *clear* question.

Comment: You call `mplayer.get("Carlsen, Magnus")` but don't capture return value. Why? --- To see if key exists, call `containsKey()`, then use `if` statement to control what you do.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you dont want to return anything from main.So change your return type to void.You can add a method which can check whether a player exists or not.
Other than that there are lots of issues.

Here

```
mplayer.get("Carlsen, Magnus");
mplayer.get("Anand, Viswanathan");
```

You are just writing statments without any if-else and not capturing the result to check that player exists or not.

I would suggest you to go through a good tutorial of java.

Answer (score 0):

1. Main should return nothing, i.e `void`

   `public static void main(String[] args){}`
2. Use Hashamap [containsKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) to identify if the player is present or not, and display appropriate message.